# PopUp window on hover

Tags: jquery

- My Problem:

I have my requirement of showing the popup window on hover of a html element.
Very important part of this implementation is, the popup should be visible even on hover of the popup window itself.

- Tried To implement:

For me the popup window is showing On hover of the target element. It is also showing on hover of the popup window. But the problem is I am only able to show the popup on hover of the popup if it is just near the target element. But if I want the hover popup to be little more in distance to the target element, the popup is getting disappeared when i bring my cursor to it. Any body implemented this scenarion?

I am using jQuery.
Following code can be reffered:

```
//Catching the mouse over event and showing the hover popup.
    $("div[id^=RestInformationHolder_div] > a").hover(
        function() {
            var control = this.id;
            var POP = this.parentNode.parentNode;
            var assetType=$("#" + POP.id).attr('_assetType');
            fillPopupContent(control, assetType);
            positionDivToTarget(this);
            showElement("restRowAnchorPopup");
        },
        function() {
            $("#restRowAnchorPopup").hover(
                function() {
                    showElement("restRowAnchorPopup");//"restRowAnchorPopup" is the popup div id.
                },
                function() {
                    hideElement("restRowAnchorPopup");
                }
            );
            hideElement("restRowAnchorPopup");
        }
    );
}

function fillPopupContent(targetElementId, assetType) {
    //Fill the content in the popup div.
}

function positionDivToTarget(targetElement) {
    var posArray = getPositionToBody(targetElement);
    var offsetLeft = posArray[0] + targetElement.offsetWidth * 1 / 3;
    var offsetTop = posArray[1] + targetElement.offsetHeight;

    $("#restRowAnchorPopup").css({ "top": offsetTop, "left": offsetLeft });
}

function showElement(elementId) {
    $("#" + elementId).css("display", "block");
}

function hideElement(elementId) {
    $("#" + elementId).css("display", "none");    
}

function getPositionToBody(targetHtmlElement) {
//Returns the relative position of the target element.
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.
Subrat.

Comment: What does your code look like? If you aren't already, start using jQuery. It'll make javascript a LOT easier... =) http://www.jquery.com

Comment: It would help if you specified the language(s) as tag(s)

Comment: any chance you can provide a live link to the site? just trying to visually get what you are after... but can't.

Comment: If you have noticed the popup you get in LinkedIn, the popup window is in a distance from the triggering element. I want something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Too lazy at the moment to code it for you but main idea is

1. User hovers your `RestInformationHolder_div` element
2. Show `restRowAnchorPopup`
3. User leaves `RestInformationHolder_div` element -> `mouseout` fires
4. You start a timer with `timerid = setTimeout(hidesPopup(), 1000)` change time to what fits you
5. If users hovers popup before timer runs out you `cancelTimeout(timerid)`
6. Else `hidesPopup()` is run and hides the popup

You can of course finetune this a bit more and make `hidesPopup()` hide the popup gradually with a "slow" opacity fadeout and if the users moves in while it is hiding you stop the animation and set the opacity back.

---

Demopage: http://jsbin.com/apaxa

Codeview of demopage http://jsbin.com/apaxa/edit

Comment: Hi jitter,
I tried to implement it but not able to get the execution of the flow properly. if you can write the code for me it would be great.

Comment: Check expanded answer for a demo of what I'm thinking about

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer but you can trim these two functions down:

```
function showElement(elementId) {
  $("#" + elementId).css("display", "block");
}

function hideElement(elementId) {
  $("#" + elementId).css("display", "none");    
}

//just call
$('#elementId').show();

$('#elementId').hide();
```